# Posting images in the page to design a shopping cart

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am having a module in my web design to upload up to 8 images, finally the main image must be on the top and other 7 images in horizontal order below the main image, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = init;
function init()
{
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var i = 0; i < td.length ; i ++ )
    td[i].onclick = changeImage;
}

function changeImage()
{
  var span = document.getElementById("main");
  span.innerHTML = this.innerHTML
}
```

```css
td {
background-color : red;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="main">Default</span>
  </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Cell</td>
    <td>Second Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

have a `div` tag for the main image and a table with one row and images being the table cell data sized accordingly. 
For the behaviour write a javascript for the table cell data, and upon being clicked change the `div` image.

for the images. have a image tag in the main div and change the src attribute of the image to the image being clicked